# Layout must contain an item for required layout field: Name

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, c#

I am trying to add a custom field to layout.
but it is giving me an error like "Layout must contain an item for required layout field: Name". I have already created the field "triggertestpkg__Branch__c" on Account.
I use metadata API Version 29.0 
I am unable to catch this error. Please advise.

```
                Layout L = new MetadataAPI.Layout();
                L.fullName = "Account-" + "Account" + " Layout";
                LayoutItem LI = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem();
                LI.field = "triggertestpkg__Branch__c";
                LI.behavior = UiBehavior.Edit;
                LayoutColumn LC = new MetadataAPI.LayoutColumn();
                LC.layoutItems = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem[] { LI };
                LayoutSection LS = new MetadataAPI.LayoutSection();
                LS.customLabel = false;
                LS.style = MetadataAPI.LayoutSectionStyle.TwoColumnsLeftToRight;
                LS.layoutColumns = new MetadataAPI.LayoutColumn[] { LC };
                L.layoutSections = new MetadataAPI.LayoutSection[] { LS };

                UpdateMetadata UpdateLayout = new UpdateMetadata();
                UpdateLayout.metadata = L;
                AsyncResult AsyncRes1 = TraverseSync.MetadataSvc.update(new UpdateMetadata[] { UpdateLayout })[0];
                while (!AsyncRes1.done)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    AsyncRes1 = TraverseSync.MetadataSvc.checkStatus(new string[] { AsyncRes1.id })[0];
                }
                if (AsyncRes1.state == AsyncRequestState.Error)
                    swLog.WriteLine("Error in Add of Custom Field : " + L.fullName + " Status Code : " + AsyncRes1.statusCode + " And Error is : " + AsyncRes1.message);
                else
                {
                    swLog.WriteLine("New Custom Field created for : " + "ACCOUNT" + " Field is : " + "Branch");
                }
```

Comment: I guess it means that you have to add the field 'Name' to your Layout as it is a required field.

Comment: I have already added the fullname of the layout and there is no field Name available for Layout object. There is only field that contains name word is fullname nothing else

Comment: You need to include the name field `li.field = "Name"` in the layout just as you would if saving the Account layout through the setup UI.

Comment: @Mehul, we're talking about the field Name of Account, not the name of the layout.

Comment: But I am not able to add both fields at a same time. LI.field only takes one field at a time.

Comment: is there any way to pass bunch of fields ?

Comment: This is an array expression that you can add many items to e.g. `LC.layoutItems = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem[] { LI, LI2, LI3 };`.

Comment: Yes. I just did that and it worked. Thank you Keith C and FrankZ

Comment: @FrankZ You should post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the field 'Name' of the object Account to the Layout.

e.g.:

```
LayoutColumn LC = new MetadataAPI.LayoutColumn();
LayoutItem LI1 = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem();
LI1.field = "triggertestpkg__Branch__c";
LI1.behavior = UiBehavior.Edit;
LayoutItem LI2 = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem();
LI2.field = "Name";
LI2.behavior = UiBehavior.Edit; 
LC.layoutItems = new MetadataAPI.LayoutItem[] { LI1, LI2 };
```

Thanks @Keith C for the joint effort.

Comment: Thank you! Here one thing to add 
LI2.behaviorSpecified = true;
LI2.behavior = UiBehavior.Requred;
Thats it. You can remove LI2.behavior = UiBehavior.Edit;